# c# can i create a dynamic file name with streamwriter?

Tags: c#, timestamp, streamwriter

I was trying to make the program write to a file that was named with a time stamp. Basically, saving a timestamp to a string value, I wanted it to create the file based on that time stamp. For example "Flight Manifest 10/14/2010 1:38:29 AM.txt"

Whats the right way to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString(), filePath = string.Format("Flight Manifest {0}", timeStamp);
MessageBox.Show(filePath);

StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(filePath);
```

Comment: ignore the the messagebox, that was just to test if the string was building correctly.

Comment: what is your problem ? after this you just have to write in your stream and dispose it

Comment: it is saying "The given path's format is not supported."

Comment: You probably need to explicitly control the date formatting as I imagine most operating systems would baulk at colons in the filename.  Try DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss").

Comment: @Paul Ruane that must have been it. It works when I control the format. I would have figured the verbatim @ would have helped, but i didn't think of the colons. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably a better way of adding timestamp to your file name would be to convert your datetime to string using some format and append to your file name. One example is given below -

```
string datetimeString = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.txt",DateTime.Now);
```

if you dont use format string, then there will be characters like '/' and ':' which are not supported for naming a file.